# How do I get public access to a 3D plot in the Wolfram cloud?

Tags: cloud-deploy

When I save a 3D plot to the cloud via:

```
CloudDeploy[Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}], 
 Permissions -> "rx"]
```

It returns a link such as:

```
CloudObject["https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/c5e46088-1341-4416-8607-dc4b0637cf16"]
```

and I can click on the link and have full 3D interactivity on my PC.  However, when I go to another PC and try the link, either the graph displays for a second then disappears and a small red box appears on the screen or nothing happens.

Can someone explain to me what is wrong?  I've tried to solve the problem myself without success.

Thanks guys,
Dominic

Comment: Maybe it's the permissions. Try  `Permissions -> "Public"`

Comment: Hi, I tried that and I still cannot access the data from another PC.

Comment: @bills likely not the permissions if he can even access it (unless somehow the `"Interact"` permission got turned off). Dominic, What does the red box say when you hover over it?

Comment: @Dominic who said `"rx"` will work?, I can reproduce the issue with it but with `"Public"` I get a nice interactive plot. You can check yourself by logging out from the cloud on a browser.

Comment: Hi guys,  the red box says, "unable to get property "sameQ" of undef or null reference".

Comment: Does my browser on the other PC need any add on in order to view the 3D plot?

Comment: Guys, how do I log out of the cloud from a browser?

Comment: Ok, I figured out how to log out of the cloud, just go to the main cloud page and log out.  And when I do that, I cannot access the plots.  I get the red box.  And this time I used : CloudDeploy[Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}], 
 Permissions -> {All -> {"Read", "Interact", "Evaluate"}}]